# maya arnold does not load the simple plugin example

Tags: maya, mel, maya-api

I try to load the simpleShader.dll into maya arnold. I have a folder with the shader .dll, .mtd and .py. and I use a userSetup.mel to define the paths, but it doesn't work. any idea?

`

//* EDDY3REE USER SETUP =========================================================================

```
// REPLACE X3_PATH below by your own Eddy3ree folder path USING FORWARD SLASH "/"
    string $X3_PATH="G:/Mon Drive/EDDY ALL WORK/3.0/Eddy3ree/Eddy3ree_01";

// ADD Eddy3ree path to MAYA env vars
    putenv  MAYA_SCRIPT_PATH        ((`getenv MAYA_SCRIPT_PATH`) + ";" + $X3_PATH);     // maya scripts & icons
    putenv  XBMLANGPATH             ((`getenv XBMLANGPATH`) + ";" + $X3_PATH);
    putenv  MTOA_PATH               ((`getenv MTOA_PATH`) + ";" + $X3_PATH);            // Arnold   
    putenv  ARNOLD_PLUGIN_PATH      ((`getenv ARNOLD_PLUGIN_PATH`) + ";" + $X3_PATH);
    putenv  MTOA_TEMPLATE_PATH      ((`getenv MTOA_TEMPLATE_PATH`) + ";" + $X3_PATH);
    
// DONE
    print("> Eddy3ree done!\n\n");
    print("> MTOA_PATH : "+`getenv MTOA_PATH`+"\n");
    print("> ARNOLD_PLUGIN_PATH : "+`getenv ARNOLD_PLUGIN_PATH`+"\n");
    print("> MTOA_TEMPLATE_PATH : "+`getenv MTOA_TEMPLATE_PATH`+"\n\n");
```

`

userSetup.mel does not work. shader does not load.

Comment: First you should avoid spaces in your paths. Arnold shows the loaded libs at startup, does it show up there? If not, start from scratch and only add the ARNOLD_PLUGIN_PATH to the environmen. I recommend to use maya.env file for this setup, you can just add a path by writing ARNOLD_PLUGIN_PATH=G:/....